# How do I write a PyTorch sequential model?

Tags: python, sequential, pytorch

How do I write a sequential model in PyTorch, just like what we can do with Keras? I tried:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

net = nn.Sequential()
net.add(nn.Linear(3, 4))
net.add(nn.Sigmoid())
net.add(nn.Linear(4, 1))
net.add(nn.Sigmoid())
net.float()
```

But I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'add'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As described by the correct answer, this is what it would look as a sequence of arguments:

```
device = torch.device('cpu')
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device('cuda')
 
net = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Linear(3, 4),
      nn.Sigmoid(),
      nn.Linear(4, 1),
      nn.Sigmoid()
      ).to(device)

print(net)
```

```
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=3, out_features=4, bias=True)
  (1): Sigmoid()
  (2): Linear(in_features=4, out_features=1, bias=True)
  (3): Sigmoid()
  )
```

Answer (score 49):

`Sequential` does not have an `add` method at the moment, though there is some [debate](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/358) about adding this functionality.

As you can read in the [documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Sequential) `nn.Sequential` takes as argument the layers separated as a sequence of arguments or an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

If you have a model with lots of layers, you can create a list first and then use the `*` operator to expand the list into positional arguments, like this:

```py
layers = []
layers.append(nn.Linear(3, 4))
layers.append(nn.Sigmoid())
layers.append(nn.Linear(4, 1))
layers.append(nn.Sigmoid())

net = nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

This will result in a similar structure of your code, as adding directly.

Answer (score 6):

```py
layerlist = []
for i in layers:
    layerlist.append(nn.Linear(n_in, i))  # n_in input neurons connected to i number of output neurons
    layerlist.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))  # Apply activation function - ReLU
    layerlist.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(i))  # Apply batch normalization
    layerlist.append(nn.Dropout(p))  # Apply dropout to prevent overfitting
    n_in = i  # Reassign number of input neurons as the number of neurons from previous last layer

    # Establish the FCC between the last hidden layer and output layer
    layerlist.append(nn.Linear(layers[-1], out_sz))

    self.layers = nn.Sequential(*layerlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

As McLawrence said `nn.Sequential` doesn't have the `add` method. I think maybe the codes in which you found the using of `add` could have lines that modified the `torch.nn.Module.add` to a function like this:

```
def add_module(self,module):
    self.add_module(str(len(self) + 1 ), module)

torch.nn.Module.add = add_module
```

after doing this, you can add a `torch.nn.Module` to a `Sequential` like you posted in the question.